# DOM как получить доступ к ноде текста элемента без текста потомков?

Tags: javascript, dom

Я делаю скрипт который выполняет функциональность вроде переводчика, т.е. он должен весть текст заменить своим, но сохранить форматирование. Есть поле у узлов innerText, но он получает и текст потомков что не нужно, и уничтожает потомков при замене если в них не было текста. Можно ли как то получить доступ только к ноде текста некой ноды документа html?

Comment: обарачивайте текст в span, например. И заменяйте его значение. Или может у вас он уже в каком-то textarea.

Comment: Я работаю уже с готовым html, я пишу пользовательский скрипт который должен работать на любой странице.

Comment: ну он же как-то определяет в каких вообще элементах нужно заменять текст?

Comment: А вы точно про узлы говорите? У узлов есть текстовый тип узла, в котором не может быть никаких дочерних узлов. Например напишите в консоль document.body.childNodes  , или ещё нагляднее document.body.childNodes[0].nodeValue = 3333333333333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У любого узла есть свойство `nodeType`, указывающее его тип. В частности, у текстовых узлов оно равно `3`, можно взять childNodes и фильтровать их по `nodeType == 3`. А чтобы в коде не было магического числа `3`, можно использовать встроенную константу [Node.TEXT_NODE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType)

```js
let textNodes = findTextNodes( document.querySelector("div") );

console.log( textNodes.map(node => node.textContent) );

textNodes.forEach(node => node.textContent = "moo");

/***/
function findTextNodes(elem) {
  return [...elem.childNodes].filter(node => node.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE);
  // childNodes - не массив, у него нет метда filter.
  // Можно любым способом превратить его в обычный массив и потом вызвать filter.
  // [...elems] → "spread operator"
}

/***/
function findTextNodes_old(elem) {
  // filter берется из обычного [] массива и вызывается в контексте elem.childNodes
  return [].filter.call(elem.childNodes, function(node) {
    return node.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
  });
}
```

```css
span { color: red; }
```

```html
<div>
  1111
  <span>2222</span>
  3333
  <span>4444</span>
  5555
</div>
```

Comment: Почему решили использовать `== 3` а не `=== 3`?

Comment: [Node.TEXT_NODE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType)

Comment: @Vasily Потому что оба всегда будут числами... или где-то есть подвох? о_О